# Bootstrap accordion opens but wont change glyphicon

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap accordion on my page and it opens and closes fine.

The only issue is when I close a section it wont change back to glyphicon-plus from glyphicon-minus, but it will change to glyphicon-minus from the default glyphicon-plus.

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="Audit">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#AuditLicence"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Expiry Dates</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="AuditLicence" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptExpiryDates" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptExpiryDates_ItemDataBound">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table id="tblExpiryDates" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Licence Type</td>
                                    <td>Expiry Date</td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr id="trExpiryDates" runat="server">
                            <td>
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"LicenceType") %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblExpiryDate" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ExpiryDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                                <%--<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ExpiryDate") %>--%>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </div> <%--Panel Body - AuditLicence--%>
        </div> <%--Panel collapse - AuditLicence--%>

    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#DrugsAlcohol"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Drugs and Alcohol</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="DrugsAlcohol" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptAudit" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Date Of Incident</td>
                                <td>Vehicle Registration</td>
                                <td>Accident Category</td>
                                <td>Fault</td>
                                <td>TP Name</td>
                                <td>Action Required</td>
                                <td>Action</td>
                                <td>Comments</td>
                            </tr>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"DateOfIncident") %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"VehicleRegistration") %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"AccidentCategory") %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Fault") %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"TPName") %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"DisciplinaryActionRequired") %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"IncidentAction") %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"IncidentComments") %>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </table>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>

            </div> <%--Panel Body - DA--%>
        </div> <%--Panel collapse - DA--%>

    </div>

</div> <%--Panel Group--%>
</div> <%--Audit--%>
```

And this is my code that I use to open and close the sections. The first part sets the open class to display the glyphicon-minus. The show and hide functions work and it will add the glyphicon-minus class when I open a tab, but for some reason it wont add the glyphicon-plus class when the tab is closed.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Add minus icon for collapse element which is open by default
        $(".collapse.in").each(function () {
            $(this).siblings(".panel-heading").find(".glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-minus").removeClass("glyphicon-plus");
        });

        // Toggle plus minus icon on show hide of collapse element
        $(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
            $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
        }).on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
            $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help much appreciated

**Edit**

I have created a test page with the same setup and done some investigation. When I inspect the **a** tag it does not show the class="collapsed" or the aria-expanded=true/false with my code, but it does on the test page.

I have tried copying the code from the test page to the system page but I am still getting the same issue no matter what I try.

Comment: It works for me: https://codepen.io/ahdigital/pen/XVWEXq Have you cleared cache?

Comment: Have you checked if it is getting into the 'hide.bs.collapse' function? Maybe place an alert('hide'); in there and see if that pops up when you close one.

Comment: @BillyMoat I added an alert and it runs the show, but not the hide. Also when add the alert instead of having two glyphicon-minus I get two glyphicon-plus

Comment: @dom_ahdigital I have cleared the cache a few times but it doesnt make any difference. Yours does work but it keeps both sections open instead of closing one

Comment: Your tags are messed up, you didn't include panel-group class either, fix your opening and closing tags and include the div containing panel-group, it should be fine then

Comment: @Highdef the panel-group class was there but for some reason not showing on the page. I have edited the code so it now appears